# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{2}+(-1)^n}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Does  the following series converge?: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{2}+(-1)^n}{n}$$

Liebnitz test shouldn't work here...Also I try to find out the partial sum sequence but it was not so fruitful ....Please help.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}+(-1)^n$ has a positive mean value hence your series is divergent by Kronecker's lemma.

Comment: What is Kronecker Lemma..?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$S_n= \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k} \right)+\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k} \right)$$

The first series diverges and the second converges by Leibnitz test...

Comment: But unless we prove the absolute convergency we cannot rearrange its terms..

Comment: @IndrajitGhosh There is no rearrangement here.

Comment: Yes. Divergence means not convergent. Then, since we have a more explicit method of proving convergence, we should assume convergence and deduce contradiction. Assume a convergent sequence ${A_n}$ and divergent one ${B_n}$, with sums $A$ and $B$, summed together is convergent.(Let the summation of A_n+B_n be C). Now, {-A_n} is convergent for ${A_n}$ is(note $\lim_{n \to \infty} -A_n=-\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n$, or $-A$. Then, $-A+A+B$ would be the sum of a convergent and convergent sequence. This would mean, though, $B$ is convergent, a contradiction.

Comment: @IndrajitGhosh Yes. And since we are talking about the partial sums, they are finite and you can rearrange.... The issues with rearranging series is that by rearranging, you change the partial sums.

Comment: @IndrajitGhosh To make the argument a bit more clear: If you assume by contradiction that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{2}+(-1)^n}{n}$ is convergent, then since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{2}+(-1)^n}{n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ are convergent, by a theorem you covered in class so is their difference $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{\frac{1}{2}+(-1)^n}{n} -\frac{(-1)^n}{n} \right)$$

Comment: @N.S. ...I understand...Thank you so much.

Comment: @IndrajitGhosh The theorem I reffer to states: If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ are convergent, then so is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n-b_n)$ and $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty ( a_n- b_n)= (\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n)-(\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n)$$

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$|\frac{1}{2}+(-1)^n|\geq|(-1)^n|-\frac12=\frac12$$
then
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\frac{\frac{1}{2}+(-1)^n}{n}|>\dfrac12\sum_{n=1}\dfrac1n$$

Comment: Uhm... But some terms are still negative, so what do you make out of that inequality?

Comment: But it doesn't mean the series is divergent....it may be conditionally convergent.

Comment: this shows the series isn't absolutely converge!

Comment: @Nosrati The other answer does show that the series diverges.

Comment: @Nosrati The first sequence in $S_n$ is divergent and the 2nd one converges to $log 2$..does it mean $S_n$ is also divergent?

Comment: yes (you mean the first series)

Comment: You can make the exact same argument about $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{2n}$., which is convergent....

Answer (score 1):

Let $A(m)=\frac {\frac {1}{2}+(-1)^{2m}}{2m}+$ $\frac {\frac {1}{2}+(-1)^{2m+1}}{2m+1}.$

We have $A(m)=\frac {3/2}{2m}-\frac {1/2}{2m+1}>$ $\frac {3/2}{2m}-$ $\frac {1/2}{2m}=$ $\frac {1}{2m}.$

Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{2M+1}\left(\frac {\frac {1}{2}+(-1)^n}{n}\right)=$ $-1/2+\sum_{m=1}^M A(m)>$ $-1/2+\sum_{m=1}^M\frac {1}{2m}$

which $\to \infty$ as $M\to \infty.$